# Discord.py file linking together

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hello there**

i wanna link to discord.py files together to use my commands that are set in another file from the
bot.py. how can i do this?

`client.load_extension('Admin_Config_Commands.Admin_Commands')`

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? Also provide relevant source files.

Comment: Please be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cog in the other file. This cog will contain the commands you want to use in the main program.

Using load extension you can load the file (with the cog inside).

Read [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load%20extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) to learn how to use load extension.

Read [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs) to learn how to create cogs.